# Compilation warning: Vector _M_end_of_storage may be used uninitialized when using list initialization for nested structs containing vectors

Tags: c++, g++, stdvector

I noticed this warning when I tried to use list initialization to initialize nested structs which contain vectors. While the code seems to perform as expected during runtime, I'm not sure why I am getting a warning during compilation. I expect the code to compile without warnings. Every member of every struct is being initialized.

Here is the minimum reproducible example I've managed to shorten my code down to:

```
#include <vector>

struct Bottom {
    int bottom_int;
    std::vector<int> bottom_vec;
};

struct Top {
    Bottom bottom;
    std::vector<int> top_vec;
};

int main() {
    Top top{
        {1, {2}},
        {3}};

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the full text of the warning I get:

```
D:/cpp/tools/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:367:31: warning: 'top.Top::bottom.Bottom::bottom_vec.std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::<unnamed>.std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_impl.std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::<anonymous>.std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl_data::_M_end_of_storage' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

I get the warning when compiling with `-O3` and `-std=c++20` or `-std=c++23` (and of course `-Wall`). I'm compiling using g++ 13.1.0 on Windows 10.

I've tried reading into the source code for vector, but I'm not familiar enough with it to understand why I get the warning. I've also tried looking it up, but none of the results seem to apply to my situation.

Strangely, slight modifications seem to make the warning disappear. Switching the order of `bottom` and `top_vec` in `Top` (and changing the initialization order of course) makes it compile without warnings, as does changing `{1, {2}},` to `Bottom{1, {2}},` even though these should not be meaningful changes.

If anyone could explain why I am getting this warning (even though my code doesn't seem to be doing anything extraordinary) it would be greatly appreciated. At this point I think it might be a compiler bug.

Comment: Seems like a compiler/library bug; you could report it to gcc, glibc or mingw depending if you can reproduce it on other platforms (try with online compilers)

Comment: Link for example: https://godbolt.org/z/eK3Y9Mjd4

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the link. Seems like a gcc issue then, I'll submit a bug report for it on their bugzilla page.

Comment: It seems to think that if one of the constructors throws an exception the destructor of the other vector will be called even though the constructor was never called.